# Parse HTML to trim it

Tags: php, html, parsing, zend-framework

Let's assume I have following piece of code:

```
<div class="content">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>dolor sit</p>
    <p><!-- pagebreak --></p>
    <p>amet</p>
</div>
```

I want to trim my code and delete everything after pagebreak, but keep html logic (`</div>`):

```
<div class="content">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <img src="#" alt="" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>dolor sit</p>
</div>
```

**Tools: Zend, regular PHP.**

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [DOMDocument](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: Is `<!-- pagebreak -->` actually a literal SGML comment or will there be some HTML entity defining where it would be?

Comment: What can you identify about where the pagebreak(s) will appear? Will the pagebreak always be inside a div with class "content"?

Comment: It will be defined by WYSIWYG editor, so 'basically' it will be in div.content>p, but I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Try this http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: why this questions is tagged in `Magento`? LOL

Comment: I would love if you took some time to have a look at my answer, it actually took me a lot of time to get that working, so just please have a quick look. Plus, I know this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use xpath to get to those nodes like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // your content with a between '<html></html>' pair
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//p[contains(comment(), "pagebreak")]/following-sibling::*|//p[contains(comment(), "pagebreak")]');
foreach ($elements as $elem) {
    $elem->parentNode->removeChild($elem);
}   

print $doc->saveHTML();
```

A little breakdown of the xpath:

- **//p** every P element.
- **//p[]** filter the list of P's, like if its an array.
- **//p[contains(comment(), "pagebreak")]** the filter is if their comment() value contains a "pagebreak" string.
- **//p[contains(comment(), "pagebreak")]/following-sibling::*** have selected P's every following sibling.
- The other part is just an union (`|`) with the same pattern without the `following-sibling::*` part.

#### Edit:

A maybe less hairy xpath would be:

```
//p[contains(comment(), "pagebreak")]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/following-sibling::*
```

This does the trick by stepping back one in the sibling list (at that point targeting the `<p>` before the the one with the comment) and has that node's `following-siblings::*`

Comment: Holy crap, that is one complicated XPath. Seems to work perfectly though, +1.

Comment: Probably could be written less verbose but I can't seem to figure out how to include `self` to the first part of the union (-:

Comment: Added a little breakdown and a maybe less dumb version too.

Answer (score 0):

I did it ! I took that as a personal challenge, and I finally did it with regexes !
This code might not be optimized, then don't hesitate to tell me how to improve it (but with regexes, not DOM), but still, it works ! :)

```
$str = '<div>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <img/>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>dolor sit</p>
    <p><-- pagebreak --></p>
    <p>amet</p>
    <blockquote>
        <p>
            lol
        <p>
    </blockquote>
</div>';


$pagebreak_str = '-- pagebreak --';
$weird_replacement = '§~@';

$parsed = array();
$is_below_break = false;

while (preg_match ("#<([^/]+)>#isU",$str)) {
    if ($is_below_break) {
        $str = preg_replace ("#<" .$pagebreak_str. ">#isU", "", $str);
        $str = preg_replace ("#<[^/>]+>(.+)</[^/>]+>#isU", "", $str);
        $str = preg_replace ("#<[^/>]+/>#isU", "", $str);
    }
    else {
        $get = preg_replace ("#^(.*)<([^/>]+)>(.*)$#isU","$2",$str,1);

        if ($get == $pagebreak_str)
            $is_below_break = true;
        if (!$is_below_break)
            $str = preg_replace ("#<([^/>]+)>#isU","$weird_replacement$1>",$str,1);
        if (preg_match ("#</([^/>]+)>(.+)(<$pagebreak_str>)#isU", $str))
            $str = preg_replace ("#</([^/>]+)>#isU", "$weird_replacement/$1>", $str, 1);
    }
}
$str = preg_replace ("#$weird_replacement#isU", "<", $str);

echo $str;
```

This code suppose you don't have any html coding mistakes, like crossing tags (<div><a></div></a>), but it's definitely working with a proper coding style.
Try it and enjoy !

Comment: Those regular expressions intervened with PHP look like after a longer period of try and error you found something that finally worked in this specific case. But I'm pretty sure it is incompatible with the syntax of HTML. Better use an existing parser or know how to parse HTML with regular expressions (not easily feasible in PHP), here is an example: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/REX.html if you want to explore further options.

Comment: Didn't say it was the ideal way of doing it. Of course DOM elements are way easier to manipulate, and way more sure.
I'll read all this documentation when I get some time.
But I did it really as a personal challenge more than anything else.
However, thanks for your answer.